# Need a regular expression to match a substring n times

Tags: javascript, regex

The regex `.*{n}` will match any single character n times, but I need to match **any single substring** n times.

How do I do that?

Comment: you ask for what? can you provide an example so it is more clear what you're looking for? and maybe explain what you did so far and where you hit the roadblock.

Answer (score 8):

To match the substring "foo" 3 times (for example "foofoofoo"), you could use the following:

```
(foo){3}
```

Or with a non-capturing group:

```
(?:foo){3}
```

As a side note, `.*{n}` wouldn't do what you think it does.  The `.` will match any character, `.*` will match any number of any characters, and `.*{n}` will vary depending on the implementation but it will either be an invalid regex, be equivalent to `.*`, or match any number of any characters followed by the literal string '{n}'.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
(your sub string here){n}
```

e.g.

```
(cats){4}
```

Comment: Just to let you know Ed, this answer is [being discussed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192259/are-potentially-offensive-jokes-e-g-sexual-innuendo-acceptable-in-answers) on Meta.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
 /(\w+)\1{n-1}/
```

Example:

`"abcbcbca".match(/(\w+)\1{2}/)` if you wish to find `bc` being repeated 3 times.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to match a given *string* repeated *n* times, just do `(string){n}`.